# Create comments for two models from comments controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

Ruby on rails newbie here, I have previously been using CakePHP and wanted to allow my create comments controller to create events for two models, any help please?

My comments controller:

```
def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @comment = @event.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  end

  def create
     @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
     @comment = @venue.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
     redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
  end
```

My create comments view:

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@event, @event.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example for polymorphic association.

There would be a bit of tweaking to get it to work right.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  ...
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  ...
end
```

This will add to your comments Model another attribute called commentable_type so you could differ the types of comments for each Model (Venue, Event)

You would have to run a migration that looks mostly like this

```
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer  :commenter
      t.text     :body
      t.integer :commentable_id
      t.string  :commentable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Now when you migrate you can go to your `rails console` and see that if you try

`Venue.first.comments << Comment.create!(:body => "Body", :commenter => "Guy") # or commenter => 1 depending on your schema`

It will be saved to the database as a comment and you can also do the same thing for `Event`

Now as for your comments controller, I would advise against creating a global comments controller and rather have follow the RESTful approach and have each controller handle his comments.

I.E

```
# routes.rb

resources :venues
  resources :comments
end

resources :events do
  resources :comments
end
```

This way you can both tweak your views according to each controller (venue / events), you follow the RESTful approach as you can use this with either HTML/JSON/XML, you get nicer routes

`/events/1/comments # index for all the comments for event 1`
`/events/1/comments/new # your add a comment form`

and same goes for venue.

You can find more info on associations in here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this Guy, very helpful, how would I go about setting up my controller?

Comment: Normal CRUDs for each model